# Updating global variable within .then()

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am making a `fetch` request that returns the usual promise. How can I get the result to be saved to a variable that I can use outside the `fetch` function?

This doesn't work:

```js
let test

fetch("[request URI]", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => { test = result } )
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));


console.log(test); // undefined
```

Edit:

```
let test

fetch("[request URI]", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => { console.log(result) } ) // here
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

works and prints the result to the console. So I am aware of how to process the result of an asynchronous request, but having trouble updating a global variable.

Comment: You have no trouble updating a global variable, that works just fine. You have trouble with timing - you're logging the global variable before it has been updated. That's why you have to call the code that needs the value from inside the `then` callback; there's no way around this.

Answer (score 0):

What happen if you try :

```js
let test

fetch("[request URI]", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => { console.log(result) } ) // here
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Yes that works - it prints the correct response to console

Comment: glad to hear it ! Can you so mark the answer as accepted ?

Comment: It doesn't answer my question - I think the comment from Bergi to my question does though.